# How can I List data which is of more than 2 GB in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have nearly 2.54GB database datas, which have tens millions of listing. 
Now I have optimized mysql query as good as I can. but still I got 10 to 12 secs to get data. SO can anyone help me what should I do now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you could do:

- If it's feasible, [optimize your database by choosing the data sizes and types which fit best](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-database-structure.html);
- [Add indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimization-indexes.html) to the most searched columns in your queries;
- Choose the right configuration parameters for your database. You should use [MySQLTuner-perl](http://mysqltuner.com/) and/or the [database configuration wizard](https://tools.percona.com/sign-in) from Percona (free registration required). Remember, tuning MySQL is a trial-and-error process; there is no "right" configuration, only one that works better for you. For instance, you could find that you get better performances with a large query cache, or with a disabled query cache altogether;
- You could move your database to a SSD drive to increase disk access times.